# String.format("%.1g", 0.0f) leads to index exception, is it a bug?

Tags: java, string

The below Java code crashes. My jdk version is 1.7.0_51. Is it a bug?

```
package testJava;

public class Test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String.format("%.1g", 0.0f);
    }
}
```

callstacks:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.addZeros(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printFloat(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.format(Unknown Source)
    at testJava.Test2.main(Test2.java:6)
```

Comment: what's the error message? also, are you sure about the syntax you've used?

Comment: Cannot reproduce, runs fine with JDK1.8.172

Comment: Does not crash in my Oracle JRE 8u191. Which JRE/JDK do you use and what error message do you see?

Comment: Thought so: what do you think that "." in your format string should achieve?

Comment: @PetrJaneček My jdk version is Oracle1.7.0_51

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: how come the stacktrace magically changed?

Comment: Not sure why this is being downvoted.

Comment: @SteveSmith my expected result is "0"

Comment: @ixp the stacktrace you show now has nothing to do with the code you show.

Comment: @Stultuske  are you sure?  It looks the same to me, assuming Test2.java:7 is the String.format line.

Comment: @SteveSmith according to the Java api's, String.format does not throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: @Stultuske ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException extends runtime exception, and is thrown by System.arraycopy().

Comment: @ixp there is nothing wrong with your code. it doesn't throw Exceptions.
The reason why it isn't printing 0, is because you didn't add a print statement to do so. put this in your main method and try again: System.out.println(String.format("%.1g", 0.0f));

Comment: @SteveSmith run his code, and you'll see there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Looks like it was a known bug that should now be fixed: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7088271

Comment: @SteveSmith Because the title was super misleading, and because the initial question content didnt have a mcve. By far.

Comment: @SteveSmith thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This was a bug in the JDK, which has now been fixed.

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7088271

"Problem in both cases is due to the specified precision being 0 or 1 when the value to be formatted is zero thereby causing an AIOOBE in Formatter.addZeros()."

Answer (score 1):

This is a [JDK bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6469160) fixed in Java 8.